# Que signifie "en tripe" ?

Tags: sens, littérature

Bonjour,

On peut lire dans *Le pont de Londres*, de Louis-Ferdinand Céline :

> *L'homme qui veut dormir c'est un monstre, il veut plus que du ventre et tout chaud, du bonheur d'enfant, toute la terre **en tripe** pour sa bouille, rentrer tout au fond tout douillet.*

Je comprends que l'auteur ironise sur ce qui serait la monstruosité et la puérilité des hommes sans conflit qui peuvent dormir sans problème, mais je n'arrive pas à comprendre le passage "toute la terre en tripe pour sa bouille".

Savez-vous ce que signifie "la terre en tripe" ici ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je comprends cette tripe (intestin) comme la représentation, par métonymie, d'un ventre maternel.

> L'homme qui veut dormir c'est un monstre, il veut plus que du ventre et tout chaud, du bonheur d'enfant, toute la terre en tripe pour sa bouille, rentrer tout au fond tout douillet.

1. *L'homme qui veut dormir est un monstre* → Le sommeil fait perdre toute humanité à l'homme ;
2. *L'homme qui veut dormir veut plus que du ventre* → Il veut encore plus que retourner à la vie prénatale ;
3. *L'homme qui veut dormir, tout chaud, veut du bonheur d'enfant* → Il veut retrouver le bonheur du bébé ;
4. *L'homme qui veut dormir veut toute la terre en tripe pour sa bouille* → Il veut le monde entier, transformé en ventre, en utérus, rien que pour lui ;
5. *L'homme qui veut dormir veut rentrer tout au fond, tout douillet* →  Il veut se retrouver au cœur ce monde devenu exclusivement sien, dans la douceur de la situation fœtale.

Answer (score 1):

Une possibilité est que c'est une métaphore qui compare la terre aux tripes, donc aux intestins humains. Ayant comme fonction l'absorption des nutriments, on verrait ici la terre, ou plutôt tous les humains sur la terre, comme étant un outil passif afin de le nourrir ou de lui fournir ce dont il a besoin. Sans plus de contexte, ce serait ma première interprétation.

Comment: Selon vous, « En tripe » est une métaphore qui dit « terre = tripes » ; donc on comprend « toute la terre terre pour sa bouille » ; cela n'est que du non-sens. Puis comme les tripes font le travail d'absorption  ce serait la terre qui absorberait, mais la terre serait  une métonymie pour  « les humains sur la terre » ; cela résulte en « toute les humains sur terre humains sur terre ». Ça ne vaut rien tout ça, c'est vraiment n'importe quoi.

Comment: La métaphore devient plausible, quand on dit que quelqu'un a de la niaque, des cou·il·les, assure face au danger, pas forcément mâle dominant, mais femme forte qui protège sa progéniture qui est sorti de *ses tripes* : c'est elle qui a de la/des tripes, celle·s de la transmission de la vie, de la naissance au/du monde.

Comment: @LPH Je ne sais si tu sais ce qu'est une métaphore mais la seule chose ici qui n'a aucun sens est ta réponse. Quel genre de raisonnement s'est passé dans ta tête pour que tu penses que "en tripe" seul sois égal à "terre = tripe". Ton raisonnement au complet sort de nulle part.

Comment: @Simon Non, pas du tout : une métaphore est quelque chose de précis ; Vous dites  « ce est une métaphore » ; qu'est-ce que « ce » ? Le PO nous demande ce que signifie « en tripe » ; La métaphore est-eelle contenue dans « en tripe », précisément ? Commment définissez-vous cette métaphore autrement ? Il nous faut tout ça.

Comment: @LPH La dernière question qu'il pose est: "Savez-vous ce que signifie "la terre en tripe" ici ?" La métaphore est "terre en tripe" pas "en tripe". C'est une métaphore explicite.

Comment: @Simon C'est loin d'être évident dans votre réponse. Seulement, donné cette précision en plus, il s'ensuit que dire « la terre en tripe » revient à comparer la terre aux tripes : le processus metaphorique n'est pas clair ; que veut dire « en tripe » ?  Il n'y a pas de réponse à cette première  partie de la question. Ne peut-on pas tout aussi bien comprendre « la terre _dans_ la tripe » ? Ces explications sont toujours loin d'être claires.

Comment: @LPH Tu réalises que la réponse de Jlliagre fait la même comparaison, mais il l'a associé par métonymie à un ventre? Ton questionnement maintenant repose sur la définition de "en", mais personne ne l'a précisé parce que l'image "dans" a beaucoup moins de sens que l'autre définition: "l'état, la manière d'être, l'aspect [...]". D'ailleurs, si ce serait "dans", je n'aurais pas parlé de comparaison entre la terre et les tripes. La métaphore serait la terre avec quelque chose dans les tripes, et mon explication aurait été différente.

Comment: @LPH Le plus gros problème ici est que tu critiques ma réponse très fortement, je cite "Ça ne vaut rien tout ça, c'est vraiment n'importe quoi, ce n'est que du non sens", alors que c'est ton interprétation qui est mauvaise, pour, au final, mettre la faute sur ma réponse. As-tu une rancune contre moi?

Comment: @Simon Amusant, une rancune contre quelqu'un que je ne connais ni d'Ève ni d'Adam ! Bien sûr que non … Il faut quand même que je fasse comprendre qu'il n'y a rien dans cette réponse qui soit convainquant, rien qui se tienne. D'ailleurs, les autres réponses ne sont pas meilleures, ou alors j'aurais fait référence à l'une d'elle pour prouver les défauts dans la votre.

Comment: @LPH On aimerait bien lire votre interprétation !

Comment: @MichelT Je n'en ai pas, je cherche une explication dans les réponses, après en avoir cherché une sur le net, et je n'en trouve nulle par. Je ne sais pas ce que « en tripe » signifie, pas plus que ce que « la terre en tripe » veut dire, et avec ça il reste le mystère de ce « pour sa bouille » (« bouille » signifie même « bouillote » en argot, et rime donc avec cette idée de sommeil qui a été insinuée). C'est complètement opâque d'après ce que je peut conclure.

Comment: @LPH Bouille veut dire tête, "pour sa tête" qui signifie "rien que pour lui". Larousse: "Familier. Visage, tête : Avoir une bonne bouille." Céline est Québécoise, alors c'est peut-être de l'argot du Québec, mais même moi je ne l'ai jamais entendu. C'est le plus plausible selon le contexte.

Comment: @Simon Louis Ferdinand Destouches, dit Louis-Ferdinand Céline, né le 27 mai 1894 à Courbevoie, pas au Québec !

Comment: @ovide Ah... Pardon, je me suis trompé de Céline. Au Québec lorsqu'on parle de Céline seul on fait souvent référence à Céline Dion! D'ailleurs, elle aime beaucoup employer ce genre d'expressions donc je n'étais pas étonné.

Comment: @simon https://www.dictionnaire-synonyme.com/synonyme-bouille

Comment: @LPH Que ce soit LF ou Dion ne change rien, *bouille* est un terme argotique signifiant *visage*. Il vient bien de *bouillotte* mais d'un *bouillotte* argotique qui signifie aussi visage, pas ce qu'on réchauffe. Il ne fait aucun doute que *pour sa bouille* signifie *pour lui* et donc que le sens est *il veut toute la terre pour lui*.  Aujourd'hui, on dit plus souvent argotiquement, [*pour sa gueule*](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/64529). Tu reconnais n'avoir absolument rien compris à ce texte mais te permets d'insulter quelqu'un qui, sans références, en a beaucoup plus compris que toi ?

Comment: @jlliagre Vous exagérez, personne n'a été insulté et je n'accepte pas ces réponses. De plus, « bouille » est un synonyme de  « bouillote » : il y a une référence ci-dessus, et il en existe d'autres, ça ne sert à rien de le nier.

Comment: @LPH … *Ce qui est amusant*, c'est l'énergie que vous mettez pour avoir raison envers et contre tous, alors que vous défendez une métaphore que vous trouvez-vous même absurde : « Ça ne vaut rien tout ça » mais au lieu d'inclure votre réponse … vous répondez *rancune* (réponse *ad hominem*) à une demande de discussion … Ah que mon doigt qui montre la lune est beau et intéressant, n'écoutons surtout le point de vue de ceux qui ne sont pas de notre avis … et pour de tels faits vous avez déjà été sanctionné … et nous avons déjà eu Causette ensemble. Je retourne au silence, comprenne qui pourra.

Comment: @LPH Si dire d'une réponse *Ça ne vaut rien tout ça, c'est vraiment n'importe quoi.* n'est pas insultant, je me demande ce que c'est. En tout cas, je vois mal comment ça correspond au "*Be clear and constructive when giving feedback*" ou au "*Be nice*" du CoC.

Comment: @Personne Non, je le repète, ça ne vaut rien sans la clé à tous ces codes puisqu'il n'y a rien à comprendre  sans ces codes ;  si après tout ce qui a été dit vous avez la réponse à la première question (« Que veut dire «  en tripe ? ») je vous envie vos pouvoirs de déduction. Je ne sais toujours pas ce que ça veut dire. Non, je ne défend aucune métaphore puisqu'on ne m'en montre aucune et que  je n'en vois aucune. Apparemment, vous ne vous en tenez pas  littéralement au contenu de mes commentaires, ou vous l'oubliez.

Comment: @LPH Est-ce que le français est votre langue native? On dirait que votre confusion vient de la préposition "en" et non du terme tripe. Ce n'est pas une façon inconnue de faire une métaphore lors d'une énumération. Voici un exemple, de ma main: "L'amour toxique ne mène à rien et son pratiquant est un homme sans ambition, une personne coincée dans une illusion, un amoureux en parasite pour le développement [...]". Cette utilisation de "en" décrit un rôle, pas un emplacement.

Comment: @Simon Cette construction (amoureux en parasite) n'est pas définie en français ;  « homme en blanc » l'est ,  « acteur en herbe » l'est aussi parce que l'on a défini « en herbe »  (https://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/16292/en-herbe/)  (https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/en-herbe/) ; « en parasite » ne se trouve nulle part, il vous faut une définition (il n'y a que la votre probablement, comment voulez-vous que l'on sache ?).

Comment: @LPH Depuis quand on a besoin d'une définition d'expression pour utiliser une préposition de façon stylistique? Je ne peux qu'en conclure que vous manquez d'expérience avec le français. Je vous invite à lire les définitions 4, 5, 6, 8 et 9 de la préposition "en": https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/en/29043

Comment: @Simon Vous voyez bien que « blé en herbe » est défini dans un dictionnaire ; comment allez-vous savoir ce que ça signifie ? Vous voyez-bien aussi qu'il n'y a pas une seule définition, mais deux ; je ne savais pas moi-même que ça pouvait signifier « prometteur ». // vos référence ne s'appliquent pas à votre construction ; la 9 s'en approche, mais il vous faut un verbe (vivre comme un parasite, prendre comme un traitre, traiter comme un étudiant, …) et en plus il y a des problèmes d'idiomaticité. Non,  par compositionalité votre construction n'est pas définie. (un amoureux comme un parasite ?)

Comment: @LPH Le cas de "en herbe" n'a aucun rapport avec la situation ici. "En herbe" est une expression qui signifie complètement autre chose, rien avoir avec de l'herbe, du gazon. Dans notre cas ici, le "en" utilise une de ses fonctions principales et présente un élément comme étant la forme, la fonction, le rôle d'un autre. L'utilisation ici s'apparente à "as" en anglais. "Lover as a parasite for development". Les 5 définitions présentées ont tous la même essence et c'est pour vous montrer ce que "en" peut accomplir.

Comment: @Simon  Désolé, je ne vois pas ce que ça signifie, et vos explications n'arrivent pas à me faire voir quelque chose que je connaisse ; je n'ai plus rien à ajouter sauf des répétitions et des détails sur ce qui a déjà été dit.

Comment: @LPH C'est une forme très littéraire et stylistique, qui apparaît seulement dans les livres et les pièces de théatre. Je ne suis pas surpris que quelqu'un qui n'est pas français ou qui manque d'expérience avec la littérature française ne comprenne pas. Par contre, je reste surpris de l'audacité de critiquer une analyse stylistique d'une langue que vous ne maîtrisez apparemment pas.

Comment: @Simon — https://argoul.com/2013/03/26/maitre-et-esclave-chez-nietzsche/ si le mouton des prés https://francais.agonia.net/index.php/poetry/1788315/Moutons donne de roboratifs méchouis, la prose du mouton nietzschéen est indigeste et devient toxique à la longue quelque soit votre totem.